# How can I iterate through multiple URLs to fetch JSON response in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am working with a third-party *API* (from company called Simpli.fi) in *Google Apps Script* to pull some data into a spreadsheet. I am able to authenticate my API call just fine and can pull all of my required data with one URL. The issue is that the way the URL to call this *API* is formatted is as follows:

https://app.simpli.fi/api/organizations/{CLIENT_ID}/{SOME_ENDPOINT}

It works when I plug in one client id and one endpoint, however I do not want to pull the data individually for each client with each data endpoint.

I wish to pull data on all of my clients and also wish to access multiple endpoints, such as "`/audiences`" or "`/campaigns`". I am hoping there is a way (similar to *Promises* in *JavaScript*) that I can iterate through multiple URLs to fetch all of the data from the API.

For now, I am simply focusing on pulling all the data I want from the "`/audiences`" endpoint for all of my clients. I have set up an array accessing my *Google Sheet* that contains all the client codes and have plugged this into the URL with a for loop, which works just fine:

```
// iterate through all URL endpoints and client codes
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('formatting');

var range = sheet.getRange(['B2:B']).getValues();
var clients = range.filter(String);
var urlOneArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
  var urlOne = [baseURL + clients[i] + '/audiences'];
  for (var j = 0; j < urlOne.length; j++) {
    urlOneArray = urlOne[j];
    Logger.log(urlOneArray);
  }
}
```

The above logs a list of each built out URL as desired.

After pushing all of the built-out URLs into the `urlOneArray`, I tried calling with `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll`:

```
for (i=0; i < urlOneArray.length; i++) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(urlOneArray[i], params);
  Utilities.sleep(500);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

When trying to use this method, I receive this error:

> "Cannot find method fetchAll(string,object). (line 35, file "Code")"

If there is a way to iterate through multiple URLs to gather all of the data from the *API* in one pull, I would really appreciate some pointers.

Here is the full script:

```
// authenticate API call
var X_USER_KEY = 'XXXX'; 
var X_APP_KEY = 'XXXX'; 

function simplifiService() {
  var baseURL = 'https://app.simpli.fi/api/organizations';

  // iterate through all URL endpoints and client codes
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('formatting');

  var range = sheet.getRange(['B2:B']).getValues();
  var clients = range.filter(String);
  var urlOneArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
    var urlOne = [baseURL + clients[i] + '/audiences'];
    for (var j = 0; j < urlOne.length; j++) {
      urlOneArray = urlOne[j];
      Logger.log(urlOneArray);
    }
  }

  var params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "x-app-key": X_APP_KEY,
      "x-user-key": X_USER_KEY
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }


  for (i=0; i < urlOneArray.length; i++) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(urlOneArray[i], params);
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    Logger.log(response);
  }  

  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    Logger.log(data);
  } else {
    Logger.log('Error: ' + response.getResponseCode());
  }
  getData(data);
}

// parse out JSON data
function getData(data) {
  var date = new Date();

  var geoFenceId = data.audiences;
  var geoFenceName = data.audiences[0].name;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Campaign Data');
  //sheet.appendRow([date, geoFenceId, geoFenceName]);
}
```

Comment: For a quick clarification -- the issue is NOT parsing the JSON data. I simply want to access the API from several URL endpoints.

Comment: Do you mean to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, not `.fetchAll()`? According to the Apps Script documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app, `.fetchAll()` only takes one object argument for the request whereas `.fetch()` takes the URL as a string as well as the parameter object.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with both ```.fetch``` and ```.fetchAll```, neither of which gives me the response I am looking for. With ```.fetch()```, I receive this error: "DNS error: http://h (line 35, file "Code")"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Issue:

- ***Invalid syntax:*** `UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(`*requests Object[]*`)` accepts object array, while you're providing a string and a object as argument.

#### Solution:

- ***Valid Syntax:*** Create a object array for each endpoint/client and provide it as a argument to `fetchAll()`

#### Snippet:

```
function copyParams() {//shallow clone params object
  for (var i in params) {
    this[i] = params[i];
  }
}
var endPoints = ['/audiences', '/campaigns'];
var requests = [];
var url, obj;
clients.forEach(function(client) {
  endPoints.forEach(function(endPoint) {
    obj = new copyParams();
    url = baseUrl + '/' + client[0] + endPoint;
    obj.url = url;
    requests.push(obj);
  });
});
console.log(requests);
var responseArray = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
console.log(responseArray);
```

#### References:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetchAll](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))
- [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)